# Many-to-Many EF relationship with a custom primary key on one side

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I feel silly asking this question, but I never had to do something like this and I am stuck.

I have a pleasure working on a legacy design that has a few "gotchas" here and there. One of them is an improperly defined many-to-many relationship between two tables. It goes like this:

### Table A

Id, Number

### Table B

Id

### Table AToB

NumberOfA, IdOfB

So to join it with SQL one would have to do something like this:

```sql
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM A
JOIN AToB ON AToB.NUmberOfA = A.Number
JOIN B ON AToB.IdOfB = B.Id
```

Yes, I know. This is a bad design. I should change it as soon as possible. And I will. But for the time being, I need a quick-and-dirty solution for the EF-based prototype. This obviously does not work

```cs
public class A
{
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class B
{
    public long Id {get; set;}
}

...

internal class BConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<B>
{
this.ToTable("B")
  .HasKey(t => t.Id);

...

internal class AConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<A>
{
this.ToTable("A")
  .HasKey(t => t.Id);

this.HasMany<B>(t => t.EntitiesOfB)
                .WithMany(t => t.EntitiesOfA)                
                .Map(m =>
                {                   
                    m.MapLeftKey("IdOfB");
                    m.MapRightKey("NumberOfA");
                    m.ToTable("AToB");
                });
```

since it expects **AToB**'s mappings to refer to A and B's primary key columns on both ends, while I expect it to use **AToB.NumberOfA=A.Number** instead, but only in this particular mapping. All other mappings using table **A** in their relationship should be still able to use it's correctly defined **Id** key column.

Does a EF6 FluentAPI solution for such case exist?

Comment: You said custom primary key. But in `Table A`, `Number` is not a key. In `Table A`, get rid of column `Id` and make `Number` primary key. Then it should work.

Comment: You can still do (manual) joins like in your example. But you cannot enforce FK relationship (thus cannot use navigation properties) in EF6. IMO you'll just waste much more time fighting it than changing the link table to use `Id` instead of the `Number`.

Comment: what @IvanStoev said..., just map it one for one as it is in EF and manually retrieve the data for now... until you change the design. This is what i do with existing database. Also you could look at EF power tools for reversing the Database into code first to see what it would have done... instead of trying to work it out... thats what i do to save shit loads of time. ;-)

Comment: You can tell EF that `Number` is `A`'s primary key (`Id` should then be a regular property). Of course I don't know if this breaks other other foreign keys to `A`. Another alternative is to bring `AToB` into your class model and define an association between `AToB.NumberOfA` and `A.Number`.

Comment: @Komengem, this would be an obvious solution if not for the fact, that I am looking for one that supports an exception to the general rule, where PK for A is Id, not a Number.